# angular-translate - StaticFilesLoader - passing prefix path dynamically

Tags: dynamic, path, prefix, angular-translate

I'm new to angularjs & was successfully able to setup angular-translate. However I want to pass the prefix path dynamically. E.g. in the code snippet below, I want to pass the country name dynamically. How should this be achieved? Please suggest.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({

    prefix: '../translate/uk/',
    suffix: '.json'
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution finally. Created a custom loader as below:

```
app.factory('customLoader',  
function ($http, $q, $timeout, $rootScope) { 

return function (options) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var filename = $rootScope.name;

  console.log('../translate/' + filename + '/' + options.key + '.json');
  $http({
    method:'GET',
    url: '../translate/' + filename + '/' + options.key + '.json'
  }).success(function (data) {
    deferred.resolve(data);
  }).error(function () {
    deferred.reject(options.key);
  });

  $timeout(function (data) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }, 2000);

  return deferred.promise;
}
```

})

Configured in app.config section as below:

```
$translateProvider.useLoader('customLoader', {});
```

And set the filename (path) from controller as below:

```
$rootScope.name = $scope.country;
```